# Dart enum generic: get enum from name?

Tags: dart

```
T getEnumValue<T extends Enum>(String name) {
  return T.values.firstWhere((e) => e.name == name);
}
```

Compiling error: T.values, T is not recognized as Enum type.

Expect to invoke the method as following:

```
 MyEnum foo = getEnumValue<MyEnum>("foo");
```